# PHP regular expressions: No ending delimiter '^' found in

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I've been having some trouble with regular expressions.

This is my code

```
$pattern = "^([0-9]+)$";

if (preg_match($pattern, $input))
   echo "yes";
else
   echo "nope";
```

I run it and get:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in

Comment: You can use [T-Regx library](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx), that doesn't need delimiters.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

PHP regex strings need delimiters. Try:

```
$numpattern="/^([0-9]+)$/";
```

Also, note that you have a lower case o, not a zero. In addition, if you're just validating, you don't need the capturing group, and can simplify the regex to `/^\d+$/`.

Example: http://ideone.com/Ec3zh

See also: [**PHP - Delimiters**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: For those who do not read linked materials, use `[` and `]` delimiters, otherwise you run into conflicts with the pattern itself.

Answer (score 26):

Your regex pattern needs to be in delimiters:

```
$numpattern="/^([0-9]+)$/";
```