# preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Tags: php, preg-match

Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in .../functions/validations.php on line 29

The code:

```
 if (preg_match($mail_pat, $email, $components)) {
```

What and where do I make the edit?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634993/php-regular-expressions-no-ending-delimiter-found-in

Answer (score 14):

A Perl-based regex should be inside the delimiters... `"/your regex here/"`... the deprecated POSIX regex were the one which did not require any delimiter... For example, ereg(").

Answer (score 8):

You must add delimiters to your regex:

```
if (preg_match('/' . $mail_pat . '/', $email, $components)) {
```

$mail_pat starts with a `^`, but it ends with another character, which causes the error since there aren't any matching delimiters.