# php warning No ending delimiter '/' found

Tags: php, preg-match, warnings, delimiter

my code shown in following

```
preg_match_all("/url=http.+?signature.+?\\/", $videosource , $videos);
```

and the output give :

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '/' found in /...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php regular expressions No ending delimiter '^' found in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634993/php-regular-expressions-no-ending-delimiter-found-in)

Answer (score 0):

You're escaping the last `/`. Try `preg_match_all("/url=http.+?signature.+?\\//", $videosource , $videos);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `/` as delimiter you can use `#~`

```
preg_match_all("~url=http.+?signature.+?\\/~", $videosource , $videos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to match a string with a backslash \ at the end and not to escape the last forward slash /. Try to match some characters with the length of 0 at the end to avoid escaping the last delimiter, e.g.:

```
preg_match_all("/url=http.+?signature.+?\\.{0}/", $videosource , $videos);
```

Comment: thankyou. i want to find anything between "url=http" and "\" .your code didn't work for me