# preg_match(): No ending delimiter '.'

Tags: php, preg-match

I've read the other responses on adding delimiters, however the line the error message is calling out does not have a '.' in it.

This is the error message:

```
Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '.' found in /homepages/17/d257823593/htdocs/includes/file.inc on line 895.
```

Here is the code(first line is line 895):

```
elseif ($depth >= $min_depth && preg_match($mask, $file)) {
          // Always use this match over anything already set in $files with the same $$key.
          $filename = "$dir/$file";
          $basename = basename($file);
          $name = substr($basename, 0, strrpos($basename, '.'));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide the values of `$mask` and `$file`? Please make an `echo` before the `preg_match`.

Comment: Chances are you'll need to append regex delimiters (e.g. `~` or `/`) to either end of `$mask`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634993/php-regular-expressions-no-ending-delimiter-found-in IMO

Comment: You ask a question about a regex but don't show us your regex. Curious.

Answer (score 1):

The first character of a regular expression is the designated delimiter and must be complemented by another one at the end (*) (**)

In your case it would seem that your `$mask` variable starts with `.`, e.g. `.something$`; you should use a proper delimiter, such as the default one:

```
/.something$/
```

(*) before the expression modifiers
(**) the ending delimiter is not necessarily the same character

[Reproduction of your error:](https://eval.in/239429)

```
$str = 'Hello test world!';
$mask = '.*';

echo preg_match($mask, $str); // Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '.' found in /tmp/execpad-2054fb2e6491/source-2054fb2e6491 on line 6
```

[Using delimiters:](https://eval.in/239431)

```
$str = 'Hello test world!';
$mask = '~.*~';

echo preg_match($mask, $str); // 1
```