# Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpMySQLSourceCode\26\data_valid_fns.php on line 17

Tags: preg-match

How to resolve this issue:

```
Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpMySQLSourceCode\26\data_valid_fns.php on line 17
```

My code is:

```
function valid_email($address)
{
  // check an email address is possibly valid
  if (preg_match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+[a-zA-Z]+$', $address))
    return true;
  else 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP regular expressions: No ending delimiter '^' found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634993/php-regular-expressions-no-ending-delimiter-found-in)

Comment: [Valid & invalid email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples)
[List of TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)
[Regex for email address (RFC 822)](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)